# Prometheus: Minimum number of instant vector samples for a valid range vector?

Tags: prometheus

What is the minimum number of samples / "vector length in seconds" required for a valid range vector, in Prometheus?

My scrape interval is `15s`.

Some observations from playing around with the `/graph` endpoint of Prometheus.

If I run the query `rate(http_server_requests_seconds_sum[Xs])` where X is:

- `30s` - does not give any data points, shows an error message
- `31s` - no data points, but no error either
- `45s` - seems flaky but shows something at least
- `60s` - shows what seems to be complete graphs (some sort of binary pulse with a duration)

So my uneducated guess is 4 samples, but would be great if someone could explain why, or link to some documentation, because I have been unable to find any information about this on the [Prometheus documentation page](https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/overview/).

Comment: It should be `rate(http_server_requests_seconds_sum[Xs])`

Comment: First, there is no minimum number of samples for a "valid range vector". If you have at least one sample in the range then you get a vector. If there's no sample in the range, you get no vector, period.

Comment: Second, Prometheus requires at least 2 samples to be present in order to compute a range. (This is unnecessary, strictly speaking, as it makes perfect sense in your case what the rate/increase is over 15 seconds; and trivial to calculate, but let's not go there.)

So your `30s` range should work just fine as long as your samples are actually spaced ~15s apart. (It will overestimate the actual rate by 2x, but it should definitely produce an answer.) What kind of error are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommendation is at least 4x the scrape interval, as you need two points to calculate a rate and between races and allowing for a failure 4x is enough.